# Why does vi think a file with extension .lrp is a tar file?

Tags: macos, debian, ubuntu-16.04, vi

I accidentally discovered that I can't edit any files that end in .lrp using vi. This is the case on OS X (High Sierra), on Ubuntu 16.04 as well as on Debian. Haven't tried any others, but this seems to occur on all of my colleagues machines as well. It's not a .vimrc setting by the looks of it either.

To reproduce, simply try to create or edit any arbitrary filename in vi, the filename needs to end in .lrp.

vi starts, but then has a red bar at the bottom stating:

```
***error*** (tar#Browse) File not readable<...path to file...>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this highly confusing matter?

Edit 1: I just wanted to add that this really sucks if you're stuck with a software package that has config files ending in .lrp you need to frequently edit manually. I can work around it creating a symlink, but that's not a nice option.

Edit 2: went through the vim sourcecode at github and stumbled across one line in this file runtime/autoload/tar.vim that declares .lrp files to be tar files... I've been around the block a few times yet never even heard of this. Perhaps an autoload option that can be disabled? my vimrc doesn't load any tar extensions or anything to would point that way.

Comment: Because you told him so. File association is set by user in .vimrc. You maybe installed a modules (for syntax highlight). But if for you `.lrp` are text file, set it so in your .vimrc. This will override other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim believes this file ending is a package of "Linux Router Project", which is compressed. Vim will try to open it with tar.
If you don't need this feature, you can disable this plugin completely.

```
let g:loaded_tarPlugin = 1
let g:loaded_tar = 1
```

Or open the file without autocommands

```
:noau e file-name.lrp
```

Comment: Excellent info, thanks! I had no idea vi(m) was loading such a vast number of plugins. Guess I was expecting it to not have evolved over the past 30 years... :)